Group PyTorch feature tensors according to labels by concatenation
I'm working on a batchable, loop and recursion free, PyTorch utility concat_aggregate for grouping rows of an input tensor x according to labels given by an  index tensor. It should pad rows so that the resulting tensor is rectangular. For example,
x = torch.tensor([[5, 50], [6, 60], [7, 70], [8, 80], [9, 90], [10, 100], [11, 110], [12, 120]])
index = torch.tensor([3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3])
concat_aggregate(x, index)

should output:
torch.tensor([
    [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
    [[7, 70], [8, 80], [9, 90], [0, 0]],
    [[10, 100], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
    [[5, 50], [6, 60], [11, 110], [12, 120]]
])

I hacked my way to this function:
def cat_aggregate(x: torch.Tensor, index: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    # Number of groups and the number of features in each row of x
    num_groups = index.max().item() + 1
    num_features = x.size(1)
    # Compute the maximum number of elements in any group
    group_sizes = torch.zeros(num_groups, dtype=torch.long, device=x.device)
    group_sizes.index_add_(0, index, torch.ones_like(index, dtype=torch.long))
    # Prepare the output tensor, padded with zeros
    max_num_elements = group_sizes.max()
    result = torch.zeros(num_groups, max_num_elements, num_features, dtype=x.dtype, device=x.device)
    # Positions to fill in the result tensor
    positions = group_sizes.clone().fill_(0)  # Current fill position in each group
    # Fill the tensor
    for i in range(x.size(0)):
        group_id = index[i]
        result[group_id, positions[group_id]] = x[i]
        positions[group_id] += 1
    return result

which returns the correct results for 1 and 2D tensors. But, it requires iterating over x.size(0), making it at least linear in the length of x. I'm not sure if what I have is idiomatic. Does anyone here see any possible efficiency/complexity improvements or an obvious way to extend it to 2D tensors? I'm surprised such a function is missing from the PyTorch API.

This should be equivalent to your function without using a for loop
def cat_aggregate(x, index):
    index_count = torch.bincount(index)
    fill_count = index_count.max() - index_count
    # fill_zeros = torch.zeros_like(x[0]).repeat(fill_count.sum(),1) ## <- Only support 2D tensor
    fill_zeros = torch.zeros_like(x[0]).repeat(fill_count.sum(),*([1]*(len(x.shape)-1))) ## <- change this to make the function takes in arbitrary shape
    fill_index = torch.range(0, fill_count.shape[0]-1).repeat_interleave(fill_count)
    index_ = torch.cat([index, fill_index], dim = 0)
    x_ = torch.cat([x, fill_zeros], dim = 0)
    # x_ = x_[torch.argsort(index_)].view(index_count.shape[0], index_count.max(), -1) ## <- Only support 2D tensor
    x_ = x_[torch.argsort(index_)].view(index_count.shape[0], index_count.max(), *x.shape[1:]) ## <- change this to make the function takes in arbitrary shape
    return x_

Output:
tensor([[[  0,   0],
         [  0,   0],
         [  0,   0],
         [  0,   0]],

        [[  7,  70],
         [  8,  80],
         [  9,  90],
         [  0,   0]],

        [[ 10, 100],
         [  0,   0],
         [  0,   0],
         [  0,   0]],

        [[  5,  50],
         [  6,  60],
         [ 11, 110],
         [ 12, 120]]])


Thank you! The one change I'd make, which was not well-specified in my question, was that stable=True flag should be added to argsort so that the items appear in the output in the order they appear in the input. For some reason, that also results in the padding always being to the right of the non-zero entries in the output, as desired. Thanks again!
